# SQL Count Statement with multiple tables

Tags: sql, count

With the below count queries I will like to have them all appear on one screen with a separator (-----------).

```
SELECT count(*) as Count_F3112 FROM PRODDTA.F3112; --> WO Routing
SELECT count(*) as Count_F4801 FROM PRODDTA.F4801; --> WO Header (Master File)
SELECT count(*) as Count_F0006 FROM PRODDTA.F0006; --> Business Unit Master
SELECT count(*) as Count_F0101 FROM PRODDTA.F0101; --> Address Book Master
```

[image: SAMPLE]

I executed the statements and the lines were separated into individual query results.

Comment: Whats the database type? SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, 'WO Routing' AS label FROM PRODDTA.F3112
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), 'WO Header (Master File)' FROM PRODDTA.F4801
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Business Unit Master' FROM PRODDTA.F0006
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Address Book Master' FROM PRODDTA.F0101;
```

Answer (score 0):

user sparator from select only '-----'

```
SELECT count(*) as Count_F3112 FROM PRODDTA.F3112
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-----------'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*) as Count_F4801 FROM PRODDTA.F4801
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-----------'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*) as Count_F0006 FROM PRODDTA.F0006
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-----------'
    SELECT count(*) as Count_F0101 FROM PRODDTA.F0101
```

Comment: depending on the database used this can error, because the columns are not the same type ('---' is string, but count(*) is numeric). Also the orde rof the results are not guaranteed

Comment: yes , you can use Cast first befor count,
cast (count(*) as nvarchar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION`!

```
SELECT count(*) as Count_F3112 FROM PRODDTA.F3112 UNION
SELECT count(*) as Count_F4801 FROM PRODDTA.F4801 UNION
SELECT count(*) as Count_F0006 FROM PRODDTA.F0006 UNION
SELECT count(*) as Count_F0101 FROM PRODDTA.F0101;
```

Comment: union can be risky if the counts from two separate tables have the same count; UNION ALL would be better, but the OP asks for a report anyway, not just 4 numbers

Comment: I've asked the OP to clarify the database type.